# Ignite Server Node with CacheJdbcPojoStore / Delay Client Node

Tags: java, spring, ignite

I'm using Spring and Ignite Spring to run a pretty simple cluster consisting of one server node and multiple client nodes with varying domain logic.

Ignite configuration:

- All nodes connect via `TcpCommuncationSpi`, `TcpDiscoverySpi` and `TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder`. `TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder.setAddresses` only contain the server node.
- The server node has serveral `CacheJdbcPojoStore` configured, the database data is loaded after calling `Ignition.start(cfg)` using `ignite.cache("mycachename").loadCache(null)`.

After a client node is connected to the server node, it does some domain specific checks to verify data integrity. This works very well if I first start the server node, wait for all data to be loaded and then start the client nodes.

**My problem**: if I first start the client nodes, they can't connect to the server node as it is not yet started. They patiently wait for the server node to come up. If I now start the server node, the client nodes connect directly after `Ignition.start(cfg)` is done on the server node, but **BEFORE** the `CacheJdbcPojoStores` are done loading their data. Thus the domain specific integrity checks do fail as there is no data present in the caches yet.

**My goal**: I need a way to ensure the client nodes are only able to connect to the server node **AFTER** all data is loaded in the server node. This would simply the deployment process as well as local development a lot, as there would be no strict ordering of starting the nodes.

**What I tried so far**: Fiddling around with `ignite.cluster().state(ClusterState.INACTIVE)` as well as setting up a manually controlled BaselineTopology. Sadly, both methods simple declare the cluster as not being ready yet and thus I can't even create the caches, let alone load data.

**My question**: Is there any way to achieve either:

1. hook up into the the startup process of the server node so I can load the data in **BEFORE** it joins the cluster
2. Declare the server node "not yet ready" until the data is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the available data structures like [AtomicLong](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-structures/atomic-types) or [Semaphore](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-structures/semaphore) to simulate readiness state. There is no need for internal hooks.

Added an example below:

Client:

```
while (true) {
    // try get "myAtomic" and check its value
    IgniteAtomicLong atomicLong = ignite.atomicLong("myAtomic", 0, false);
    if (atomicLong != null && atomicLong.get() == 1) {
        
        // initialization is complete
        break;
    }

    // not ready
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Server:

```
...

//loading is complete, create atomic sequence and set its value to 1
ignite.atomicLong("myAtomic", 1, true);
...
```

UPDATE#2

instead of having a self-written-loop including `Thread.sleep`, `latch.await()` can be called. See: [countdownlatch](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-structures/countdownlatch)

Comment: Could you please elaborate how AtomicLong or Semaphore would help in this situation? I basically have to check inside the client nodes, if the server nodes AtomicLong is set?

Comment: Yes, a client will be checking if, say, AtomicLong is present and is set to some value. If not - wait. The server on the other hand will initialize and set the value only after #loadCache is finished.

Comment: Well, I got that. But how do I get access to the AtomicLong? All services have their own virtual machine, so a simple access - e.g. via Singleton or something is not possible.

Comment: Ok, maybe there was confusion in terminology, Ignite data structures like IgniteAtomicLong are backed by a special cache and are distributed across different nodes. I'll update the answer with a short example.

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't know that Ignite provides such data structures. This solution fits perfectly, is simply and effective. Implemented it based on your sample code in like 30 seconds - works like a charm!

Comment: Small update: I looked up the documentation. IgniteCountDownLatch is fitting even better. Instead of having a self-written-loop including Thread.sleep, latch.await() can be called. See: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-structures/countdownlatch. Maybe you want to update your code example accordingly?